# Is the /k/ sound in McDonald considered syllabic? (and insertion of /@/ when pronouncing syllable onsets)

Tags: phonetics, syllables

Using the formal syllable identification rules, you have the following (with an example pronunciation):

```
MacDonald => Mac + Don + ald (`/məkdˈɒnl̩d/`)
McDonald  => McDon + ald (`/məkdˈɒnl̩d/`)
Kvitova   => Kvit + o + va (`/kəvˈɪtəvə/`)
```

Here, the number of vowel sounds (syllabic or not) in the last two examples does not match the syllable split. A (`/ə/`) has been inserted between two of the consonants.

Does this pronunciation pattern change the syllabification rules to align with the number of spoken vowel/syllabic consonant sounds, or is it more a pattern of speech to smooth over adjacent consonants that do not flow easily together (e.g. the `kv` pair in `kvitova`)?

With `Mc`, should this be considered a prefix like `be`, `de` and others are, and be considered a syllable on its own -- that is, should it follow the syllable pattern of `MacDonald`?

If `Mc` should be considered a syllable, is the `c` the nucleus? If so, does that make the `/k/` phoneme syllabic?

Comment: You seem to be confusing spelling and pronunciation. Syllables are about sounds and Eglish spelling is notoriously not in a diretion 1:1 relationship with its pronunciation.

Comment: I know that there is not a 1:1 relationship between spelling and pronunciation and that different accents have different pronunciations. I also know that syllables are about sounds (i.e. the number of vowel sounds in a word). Here, the `Mc` has the `/@/` vowel, so should be considered a syllable. However, there is no vowel to be the nucleus. Therefore, the letter `c` should form the nucleus and `@k` should be syllabic. That is, you don't pronounce `McDonald` as `/mkʼdˈɒnl̩d/` or similar (i.e. an ejective or implosive `/k/`).

Comment: There is a vowel to be the nucleus, `/@/` as you have written, I'm assuming schwa. Letters don't form nuclei, sounds do. You have a string of two letters representing a string of three sounds. You pronounce `McDonald` as `/m@kdon@ld/` or `/m@kdonld/`, etc.

Comment: This is precisely where you unambiguously confuse letters and sounds: "as there is no vowel present to form the /ə/ sound". There is a vowel (sound) present. There is just no letter for the vowel.

Comment: @hippietrail I do not understand what you mean? Do you mean that there needs to be a vowel letter to be the nucleus (spelling), or that there needs to be a vowel sound (phoneme) to be the nucleus? If it is spelling, then the `McDon` syllable has two vowel sounds (`/mək/` and `/dɒn/`) which would not make it a syllable.

Comment: May I say that this is an extraordinarily stupid question. "Mc" is just an abbreviation of "Mac". Are you going to tell us that "Mister" has two syllables and "Mr" has none?

Comment: @hippietrail So if I understand you correctly, `McDon` is a syllable which is pronounced with two vowel sounds (/məkdɒn/). Note that wikipedia says that the nucleus may be a syllabic consonant, and the word `shh` has no vowel to form the nucleus, so the /ʃ/ is syllabic (i.e. `/ʃ̩/`) -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant#Obstruents.

Comment: @flb Why is it a stupid question? You are arguing that McDonald has 3 syllables, but hippietrail seems to be arguing that it only has 2. The syllable analysis rules agree with hippietrail. A similar thing applies to names like `kvitova`. I'm interested in how syllables correspond to pronunciation. So really, the question relates to the insertion of `/ə/` in the consonant sequence of a syllable onset.

Comment: hippietrail nowhere argues that `McDon` is a syllable. He says that `Mc` is a syllable whose nuclear vowel /ə/ is not represented **in the spelling**. He denies your claim that it has no nuclear vowel.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense now.

Comment: In a language like Georgian `/mkdon/` could be a syllable, but English phonotactics disallows the consonant cluster `/mkd/`. I'm pretty sure that stops cannot be syllabic consonants but only consonants with continuing sound such as laterals, sibilants, and nasals.

Comment: @hippietrail what a strange cluster :). I wonder how it sounds in reality

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The strangest cluster in Georgian is gvprtskvn (გვფრცქვნ)! The strangest common cluster I know is mtsvrtn (მწვრთნ). Languages like Adyghe probably have much stranger ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is **no** reasonable analysis under which "mcDon" is a syllable. It is two syllables, irrespective of whether you write an 'a' in it or not.

"Kvit" (or "kvi") is one syllable except for those people who find it impossible to pronounce the cluster "kv", and for them it is two syllables.

Comment: Indeed.  The syllabification rules in English do not admit `mkd` as an onset.  I'd be interested to know about other languages, though my guess is that it's seldom admissible there either due to sonority ordering.